# how to achieve 2.5D world using Box2d

Tags: box2d

is it posible to create a 2.5D world for a game like this one (Double dragon) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb9P0YTeq5Y using box2d?

do you know of any working example?

Thanks beforehand, for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Only an idea. I didn't test it.

First you would have to animate your sprites to give the illusion of moving in the Z direction. :-)

Then you could use collision filtering to manage the collisions according to the positions of your characters.

Box2D allways have to know if two bodies collides before deciding if they will collide or not in your scene.

At each collision of each character you could test the Y position of the others characters and scene bodies, then make tests :

- If the collided body is (approximately, with a threshold corresponding to your character "depth") at the same Y position you **change the collision group** of the collided body to perform the collision with bodies characteristics.

  Look at this excellent tutorial, at the end you have the tip to manage your collisions by using the b2Filter in a custom function : http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering

  You might want to take a look too at http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8738#p37119 to handle the first contact.
- If the collided body isn't at the same Y, or is a "friend", you do nothing and they do not collide in the scene.

Hope it helps.